# how to make a discount price after user have logged in

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, cookies, codeigniter-3

I need to set discount price in all products in store with discount 10% after the user have logged in. Anyone can write me a simple code for my problem? it has killed me out. i am new in my team for making a web store,  and the crazy i am just in there less then 2 weeks.

i am afraid to give my code here(this is not my code, but my team code),  because the code is too long with 600+ line.
first i know i need session or cookies for the user login. But i don't know where i need put the cookies of user login and the discount price

this is the controller that i have tried to do

```
function discount_item(){
    $login = $this->Content_m->m_check_login();
    if($login == 1){
    $product_info=$this->Product_m->m_get_product_by_id();
    if ($product_info['product_discount']>=0 && $product_info['product_discount']= NULL);
        $product_discount = (($product_info['product_price']*10)/100);
        $_SESSION["cart"]["item"]["product_".$product_info["product_id"]] =$product_discount;
    }
}
```

is that a true statement?

this is my model for checking who user is logging

```
function m_check_login(){
    if(isset($_COOKIE["user_login"])){
        $user_info=$this->m_get_user_by_email($_COOKIE["user_login"]);
        $user_desktop_login = $user_info["user_desktop_login"];
        if($_COOKIE["user_secure"] == $user_desktop_login){
            $data =  1;
        }else{
            $data = 0;
            setcookie("user_secure", "expired", time()-3600,"/");
            setcookie("user_login", "expired", time()-3600,"/");
        }
    }else{
        $data = 0;
        setcookie("user_secure", "expired", time()-3600,"/");
        setcookie("user_login", "expired", time()-3600,"/");
    }
    return $data;
}
```

and this is for the view for discount price when user have logged in only

```
<?php
                       if($login == 1){
                           if($product->product_discount != null && $product->product_discount > 10){
                               $product->product_discount = $product->product_discount;
                           }else{
                               $product->product_discount = 10;
                           }
                       }
                       if($product->product_discount != null && $product->product_discount > 0){
                           $price_after_discount = $product->product_price -(($product->product_price*$product->product_discount)/100);
                           ?>
                           <span style="font-size: 17px;text-decoration: line-through;color: #ccc;"><em>$<?=$product->product_price?></em></span>
                           <span style="color: #5169a5;">$<?=$price_after_discount?></span><br>
                           <span class="label label-danger" style="padding: .2em .3em .2em;font-size: 70%;border-radius: 0;background-color: #e81f1f;position: absolute;top: 0;right: 0;font-family: roboto;">
                               off <?=$product->product_discount?>%
                           </span>
                       <?php }else{ ?>
                           <span>$<?=$product->product_price?></span>
                       <?php }?>
```

Comment: create a function for checking whether user is logged-in or not and whenever user is logged in and function returns true apply the discount for each product

Comment: do u mean in modal ? @Vicky

Comment: It depends what you are doing with the method, but I probably wouldn't modify the actual session item price (unless you were specifically told to do that). I would have a discounting element to the session that stores discounts for later processing which you would only access when displaying the price on the page or when you go to do the final check out.

Comment: yes i will only show the price when customer is trying to find the product,  than the price will display depend on the product. i use logged in just for when the customer has logged in, all of the price of the products will get 10% discount. @Rasclatt

Comment: I realize that but are you not updating the original price in the session?

Comment: I am suggesting not to do that (unless you were explicitly told). The reason for that is because then you have hardcoded that which leaves your discounting static and rigid. Now if you wanted to build in another discount of some sort later on, you now have to add another hardcoded algorithm for that. I am suggesting you store in the session instructions for the cart discount(s) and use a form of automation to calculate at the time of output.